# How to replicate a dripping material or mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, procedural

Posting this again. Previously the asset was not viewable as it was a link to an Instagram post. Please view the link in the file I have uploaded the video.

I am trying to see how to replicate this material in blender from this artist. Please see Video here. https://arifqz.github.io/files/127264400_368795457682043_378612915796313300_n.mp4

Credit goes to the artist here. http://www.alexkiesling.com/animation-1

I am fairly certain they did this in Cinema 4d

Can it be done procedurally? or a particle system?

Thanks. i did a few searches and wasn't able to find the look I was going for

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: hey @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Apologies I will do better on posting future questions. I was just following the instructions from the previous post when a question has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *exactly* the same, but try something like this - it just takes a Voronoi texture as a displacement and pulls it "down" on the Z-Axis. Enter *#frame* in the value node to make the value match the current frame (makes it move when you "play the scene).

[image: Displace]

Remember you need to be in cycles and have a heavily subdivided object for the displacement to work. You also need to enable "displacement only" or "displacement and bump" under the materials settings.

Looks like this - it actually looks much better/smoother, I just had to go low-res for a .gif small enough to upload - this is only a 3 second repeating clip:

[image: Move]

Also, I just noticed, you can probably make it match your sample a bit closer if you choose *Smooth F1* on the Voronoi texture.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip. I am trying to set it up with the node configuration. I have #frame in the value node and have copied the node set up but for some reason its not behaving like the gif you posted.

Here is a link to the blend file on google drive.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ja7CTi02pZAsfl2BEMc1Vba5qZhzhyA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your _Map Range_ node has the input range mapped to a space between 1 and 1 (no space at all). Change the _To Min_ to something like .6. HOWEVER - your mesh seems oddly subdivided. For the best results, start with a cube, add a subdivision surface modifier (catmull clark level 3) and apply it. Then add a _Cast_ modifier set to sphere (default) and change the  _Factor_ to 1. Apply that as well. Then, add another subdivision surface modifier (level 3 or 4), but don't apply it. This should give you a sufficiently subdivided "quad-sphere" (no tri's or poles) - optimal for displacement.

Comment: Also, you probably want to reduce the multiplication of the frame speed to something like 0.02.